# jQuery - Improving Performance / Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I just started working with jQuery and I have been searching for some type of resource on how to improve the speed/performance of my code. I was wondering if anyone had any tips or resources that could possibly help me out.

Thanks,

Bev

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had a few sites bookmarked on this very topic, hopefully they will help you out with what you need. (Topics range from simple to advanced)

[jQuery Performance Rules](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/) topics include :

> 1. Always Descend From an #id
> 2. Use Tags Before Classes
> 3. Cache jQuery Objects
> 4. Harness the Power of Chaining
> 5. Use Sub-queries
> 6. Limit Direct DOM Manipulation
> 7. Leverage Event Delegation (a.k.a. Bubbling)
> 8. Eliminate Query Waste
> 9. Defer to $(window).load
> 10. Compress Your JS
> 11. Learn the Library

[jQuery Performance and Optimization Tips](http://addyosmani.com/blog/8-jquery-performance-tips/) topics include :

> 1. Stay up to date! Are you using methods and techniques that are obsolete?.
> 2. Context-aware jQuery Code Execution – Are you loading code that isn’t needed?
> 3. jQuery Unit Testing
> 4. Benchmark Your jQuery Code
> 5. Keep download times to a minimum with one compressed master JS file.
> 6. Context Vs. Find
> 7. Window.load all the way.
> 8. Strike A Balance Between Your Use Of JavaScript & jQuery

[jQuery Performance Tuning Tips - Paul Irish](http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-advanced-jquery-performance-tuning-tips-from-paul-irish) topics include :

> 1. Optimize selectors for Sizzle’s ‘right to left’ model
> 2. Use live() not click()
> 3. Pull elements off of the DOM while you play with them
> 4. Use find() rather than context
> 5. Use HTML 5
> 6. Append style tags when styling 15 or more elements
> 7. Test selectors using Google Page Speed
> 8. Use object detection even if jQuery doesn't throw an error
> 9. Use direct functions rather than their convenience counterparts
> 10. Learn the lesser known methods

[Improving jQuery Performance with Large Data Sets](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/5-easy-tips-on-how-to-improve-code.html) topics include :

> 1. Use JavaScript native for() loop instead of jQuery's $.each() helper
>      function.
> 2. Do NOT append an element to the DOM in your loop.
> 3. If you have a lot of elements to be inserted into the DOM, surround them
>      with a parent element for better
>      performance.
> 4. Don't use string concatenation, instead use array's join() method for
>      a very    long strings.
> 5. Use setTimeout() function for your long list looping and concatenation
>      functions.

Hopefully these will be enough to get you started on your journey to jQuery performance heaven.

Comment: +1 great post.  Also, in the name of Teaching A Man To Fish, this link may be helpful:  http://www.google.com/search?q=ways+jquery+performance

Comment: I think the advice to use `.live()` instead of `.click()` (etc) is good, but even better advice is to use `.delegate()` instead.

Comment: The second source seems to be very dissonant for me. *2. Are you loading code that isn’t needed?* vs *"5. Keep download times to a minimum with one compressed master JS file."*. Also *"7. Window.load all the way."* - your users might argue with that...

Comment: In fact the fans of fancy JavaScript loader toolkits like LabJS would argue that it's a little faster to load *two* scripts rather than just one combined script. Personally I'm not so sure it's worth the hassle, but web client performance is certainly a fast-moving target.