# Optimization of a jquery dom explorer code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, optimization, checkbox

How do I to make this [code work](http://jsfiddle.net/Eg4eV/1/) with a better performance, please ?

Rules :

- If the `option[value='admin']` is selected, check all the checkboxes. If not, uncheck them all.
- If a checkbox is checked, change its value to `true`, if not to `false`.
- If `.gestionSupervision && .gestionSupervision2` are checked, check all checkboxes and select `option[value='admin']`.
- If `.gestionSupervision && .gestionSupervision2` are unchecked, select `option[value='sei']`.
- If `.gestionSupervision` is checked, `.gestionSupervision2` must be.
- If `.gestionSupervision` is unchecked, `.gestionSupervision2` must be.
- If `.gestionSupervision2` is checked, `.gestionSupervision` must be.
- If `.gestionSupervision2` is checked, `.gestionSupervision` must be.

**Please note** the hidden checkbox.

Comment: Cache your selectors!!! Use chaining!

Comment: Not looking up selectors $(".gestionSupervision2") multiple times will help (lookup once & store a reference)

Comment: @Bergi, can you please show me how I'm new to this?

Comment: @AlexK., can you please show me how I'm new to this?

Comment: See point 5 @ http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/

Comment: Nope, you should be able to find out yourself with the hinted buzzwords :-) Try it, then ask again. If you want a general feedback you might post your code at [codereview.SE]. See possible duplicates [jQuery - Improving Performance / Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700097/jquery-improving-performance-code), [jQuery Optimization/Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230727/jquery-optimization-best-practices) and [jQuery pitfalls to avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229259/jquery-pitfalls-to-avoid)

Answer (score 0):

First, you can save your selector in a variable like this:

```
var gestionSupervision2 = $(".gestionSupervision2");
```

So you'll be able to refer to it, avoiding to query the DOM every time

Then you can also set all properties in one selector using:

```
gestionSupervision2.prop({
                    'checked', true,
                    ...
 });
```

Remember to remove the attribute *disable* for actually enabling the element:

```
$('.gestionSuperVision2').removeAttr("disabled").
```

You'll end up with something like:

```
    $(".gestionSupervision2").prop({'checked': true,value:'true'}).removeAttr("disabled");
```

jquery will do the rest for you behind the scenes. Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes it does, and thank you so much for your response !! But, does the code work with that?

Comment: Can you please show me the result in jsfiddle, because I have [edited it as you mentioned](http://jsfiddle.net/Eg4eV/2/), but, with any succes result.

Comment: To be sure that your code works, try to write into jsFiddle, and then share the result. Because, when I add what you've mentioned, this wouldn't work. I am grateful for your effort.

Comment: ah, sorry, can't do it now, I'll do it in a couple of hours, but what I can see is that you have some lines where you set disable with different values in the same selector like
 $(".gestionSupervision2").prop(
                    'disabled', false,
                    'checked', false,
                    'disabled', true,
                    'checked', false
                );